# Nodemailer can't access info from .env

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

Can't get Nodemailer to send messages to my yahoo mail inbox.  When a message is sent, I get a message that says "ReferenceError: processs is not defined".  My interpretation is that it cannot access my .env file.  I've been trying to solve this all day long. I originally had it connected to my personal gmail account, it worked at that point.  Then I tried to connect it to a different gmail account, at which point it stopped working.  I figured it was because I had to get an auth token or something from google, so being as my client uses Yahoo mail, I created a yahoo email account to connect it to, and that's where I'm at right now.  I've been trying all day long. Here is my nodemailer method:

```
require('dotenv').config()
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


module.exports = {
    sendEmail: (req,res) => {
        console.log('-----hit', req.body)
        const { name, email, text } = req.body
        console.log('req.body', name, email, text)

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'yahoo',
  auth: {
    user: processs.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
    pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASSWORD
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
})


var mailOptions = {
  from: name + ' ' + process.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
  to: process.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
  subject: 'New Message From ' + name,
  text: name + ' ' + email + ' ' + text
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
})
}}
```

Comment: There's a typo in the user value: user: `processs`

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. I added an answer with this information so you can mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the `auth.user` value: `processs`